# inserting id corresponding to a item in combobox in database using c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, oledb

```
      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

        string Sql = "select project_name from tb_project";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(Sql, con);

        con.Open();
        OleDbDataReader DR = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (DR.Read())
        {
            combo_status.Items.Add(DR[0]);
        }

        con.Close();

      }
```

in this code i am fetching project name from a table in database and showing them in combobox but what i want is that in this is that in the table from where i am fetching project name there is a project id corresponding to that name...so i want project name to be displayed in combox and when i click on submit then it should insert project id corresponding to the project name choosen in combobox so how can i do that.....

Comment: Since you say Combobox, I assume this is Windows application, not web, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` Of Combobox

```
// Fetch Both Project Name and Project Id    
string Sql = "select project_name, project_id from tb_project";
con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
com = new OleDbCommand(Sql, con);
con.Open();  

OleDbDataReader DR = com.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt;  
dt.Load(Dr);
combo_status.DataSource = dt; //Check it this works or not

combo_status.DisplayMember = "project_name";
combo_status.ValueMember= "project_id";
```

### To get Project_id of Selected project_name

```
Int64 varproject_Id =  Convert.ToInt64(combo_status.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: could you please tell me in detail the method of writing the code...i am new to c#.net..please

Comment: instead of `DataReader`, the datasource must be a `DataTable`

Comment: i have to fetch multiple names from database...for that do i have write this code in a loop or something??

Comment: your Sql query fetch multiple names from database and set it as datasource of your combobox. Try  above updated code

Comment: private void btnSave_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert Into tb_property(bedroom) Values (@pname)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pname", combo_status.Text);
           
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted sucessfully");

        }

Comment: this is my code for inserting data but it isstill inserting the name instead of id...what to do now...??

Comment: use combobox.SelectedValue

Comment: it is working fine now...but i wanted to ask one more thing and the thing is that now it is showing the project name in combobox but on page load i want to show "select " text in combobox....so how to achieve this??

Comment: Why you want to do this and this is a differnt question so post this question seperately describng all details whatever you want

Comment: actaully this field is optional...so wanted to know it

Comment: If you always want to add it add a row to Datatable want to know how it work refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while (DR.Read())
{
   combo_status.Items.Add(DR.GetValues(0).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string Sql = "select project_name, project_id from tb_project";
con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
com = new OleDbCommand(Sql, con);
con.Open();  

OleDbDataReader DR = com.ExecuteReader();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Load(dr);
combo_status.DataSource = table;
combo_status.DisplayMember = "project_name";
combo_status.ValueMember= "project_id";
```

Comment: Its a copy of my answer

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to insert the project id of the selected project name in some other table. To accomplish this you can use following code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Sql = "select project_id, project_name from tb_project";


        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(Sql, con);


        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);
        da.Fill(ds);
        combo_status.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        combo_status.DisplayMember = "project_name";
        combo_status.ValueMember = "project_id";
        com.Dispose();
        con.Close();

    }
```

In this way you will find the project name using combo_status.SelectedText and you will find the project id using combo_status.SelectedValue. Now you can use it anywhere you want.